# What did Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station Do? What sensors did it have and how did it record data?

Tags: radio-shack

[@Ruslan's excellent answer to *What it the outer part of the sun, that we see with our eyes, called?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44921/7982) and its link to David R. Brooks' [Photographing the Solar Aureole](https://instesre.org/Solar/AureolePhotography/Aureole.htm) led me to Forest M. Mims III (2003) in Applied Optics 42, (3) 492 [Solar Aureoles Caused by Dust, Smoke, and Haze](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-42-3-492&id=71016) (also [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10915605_Solar_Aureoles_Caused_by_Dust_Smoke_and_Haze)) and the author's other pages

- https://sunandsky.net/Sky_Photos.html
- http://www.forrestmims.org

the latter of which mentions the **RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station**. Below is a GIF from that page.

**Question:** What did Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station do? What sensors did it have and how did it record data?

**disclaimer:** I have no affiliation to the product, which I believe is no longer available in any event.

The GIF http://www.forrestmims.org/images/210_Animation_Sun_Sky_at_White_Sands_DSCN1722.gif won't play more than once in my browser once I embed it here as https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv3YW.gif so here are the five individual images; I've enlarged and sharpened them.

[image: frame 1 of 5 from the GIF Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org] [image: frame 2 of 5 from the GIF Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org]
[image: frame 3 of 5 from the GIF Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org] [image: frame 4 of 5 from the GIF Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org]
[image: frame 5 of 5 from the GIF Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org]

Five frames from the GIF fo Forest S. Mims III's RadioShack Sun & Sky Monitoring Station from http://www.forrestmims.org

---

For more Sun monitoring equipment see the following in Earth Science SE:

- [What are these Gizmos at Izaña Atmospheric Research Center in Spain?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16726/6031)
- What are these Gizmos at Mauna Loa Observatory?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16478/6031)
- [What is a Rotating Shadowband Radiometer, and how does it work?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16481/6031)

Comment: I think this may push the boundaries of retrocomputing; looking at the circuit board I'm not sure there is a real computer inside, but folks here may have some experience tracking down vintage RadioShack electronics so I think this is where answers are most likely to be forthcoming. Maybe keep it open long enough to get answered at least?

Comment: It really does, this is neither a computer or contains one (unless the clock is coutned as such) nor is it retro in any way.

Comment: [Can buy on Amazon today](https://www.amazon.com/Sun-and-Sky-Monitoring-Station/dp/B000I68M2O) ::= not retro.

Comment: @another-dave ah, I was thinking about asking for a working definition; I see [computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but if "...and can not be found on Amazon." is part of the site's working definition, then maybe that should be added to help on-topic?

Comment: I have flagged as off-topic, as it's not about computing, and is not retro (per se)

Comment: @ScottEarle I understand, and the current answer seems pretty conclusive already. Hopefully it was a *vote* and not a flag.

Comment: @uhoh well, Amazon is kind of an indicator, as most of their stuff is new. They're not Ebay. It's just less of a sharp distinction than the Tandy catalogue. I do not believe there's any sense in listing various sales channels - but this may be rather up to be talked about in Meta.

Comment: @another-dave can buy **new** on Amazon today .EQ. not retro. I can buy any number of C64 games *used* on Amazon: does that mean we can't discuss them?

Comment: Maybe we can debate the issue when we see a System/360, new or used. for sale on Amazon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't find a manual, but there's a fair description of what we're seeing in those pictures [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210720000702/https://www.weather-watch.com/smf/index.php/topic,8807.msg62720.html):

> It's basically 4 LED's being used as sensors, connected to an op-amp and voltmeter.  Literally less than $5.00 worth of parts.

Mims's thing is using LEDs to measure solar irradiance. While they do respond to solar intensity quite well, calibrating and interpreting the output is not easy. Mims has used his tech pulpit to cast doubt on anthropogenic climate change and also promote intelligent design.

As the device contains no computing elements, I'd like to suggest that it's out of scope for this site.

Comment: What is the purpose of your sentence about Mims' "tech pulpit".  Are you saying your belief that _his_ beliefs are ... unviable ... imply that his technology is also unreliable?  _Ad hominem_?  Or?  I don't see how that sentence improves your answer at all.

Comment: @davidbak it does when read as whole. The tech used is at best unreliable, delivering hard to calibrate and repeat results, thus any usage is at least doubtful. In conjunction with a promoter known to support fringe opinions (to say it friendly) the whole usage needs to be marked as done.

Comment: Okay I think this pretty much sums it up, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @uhoh - try it now: I fixed it. You'll have to scroll down to find the text, which I quoted in its entirety.

Comment: @davidbak His experiments and methodologies are guided by his beliefs, which is not how the scientific method works. It's not *ad hominem* if the person is misguided and is publishing results not supported by scientists. I'm with the IPCC on this one: when Mims tried to include works that would weaken the findings and standing of the report, they rejected it because Mims cited no peer-reviewed research.

Comment: @davidbak ad hominem is a valid way to adjust your a-priori probability of something being quackery or not. If most things with property P are quackery, and this thing has property P, it's a good guess that it's quackery. In this case property P is that the thing is "recommended" by a certain person